# Hohe to Chance HyperLink foreground color

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I want a HyperLink to be created with text/or url coming in blue color and underlined.

With below code I am getting only underlined link. No blue color is coming.
What should be done to make it blue.

```
Hyperlink infoLink = toolkit.createHyperlink(parent, url, SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK | SWT.COLOR_LINK_FOREGROUND);
    infoLink.setHref(url);

    infoLink.setForeground(infoLink.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_BLUE));
    infoLink.setEnabled(true);
    infoLink.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false,false));
    toolkit.adapt(infoLink, true, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that you do not need to call `adapt` on something that was created by the form toolkit.

`Hyperlink` controls created by the tool kit are added to `HyperlinkGroup`. The group controls the colors.

Get the group with:

```
HyperlinkGroup group = toolkit.getHyperlinkGroup();
```

You then have `setForeground`, `setBackground`, `setActiveBackground` `setActiveForeground` and `setHyperlinkUnderlineMode` methods you can call to set the links style.